# Angular validation locking input because of $compile?

Tags: angularjs, validation

Fiddle to reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/cp6eydb1/1/

I noticed that inputs that have run through `$compile` are behaving weird when it comes to out-of-the-box validation, but am not sure if I am doing something wrong.

```
.directive('dummydirective', ['$compile', '$timeout', function ($compile, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {},
            replace: true,
            // notice how the field has type="email", which triggers email validation
            template: '<input type="email" name="booger" ng-model="bim">',
            link: function (scope, element) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $compile(element)(scope);
                });

            }
        };
    }]);
```

I have situations where the field is blocked entirely, I can only fill the model when pasting a valid string (i.e. valid email address). Char-by-char input is blocked (one char is not a valid email address).

In the jsfiddle there's weird behaviour, you can see filling the field is working, but as soon as you start removing input (which renders the field invalid) strange things happen. The field is emptied, and input is blocked. However, pasting a valid email address at once does work.

What is going on here? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best fix for now is cloning the element, this appears to work also in nested directives without removing validation or locking the field:

```
var clonedEl = element.clone();
element.replaceWith(clonedEl);
element.remove();

$compile(clonedEl)(scope);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cp6eydb1/3/

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the exact reason behind weird behaviour but You could try something like this

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

So, change directive as shown below

```
.directive('dummydirective', ['$compile', '$timeout', function ($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        replace: true,
        // notice how the field has type="email", which triggers email validation
        template: '<input type="email" name="booger" ng-model="bim">',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

Now, Its working fine. Here is the updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cp6eydb1/2/

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks, it works in some cases, but sometimes removes the validation entirely (probably when directives are nested and $compile is run on multiple levels). When cloning the original element, and using `element.replaceWith(clonedEl)` it seems to work. Kind of overkill, but what can we do.